# If a variable is empty, I want PHP/MySQL to assign a different value to the variable

Tags: php, mysql, null

Imagine this select statement in MySQL:

```
SELECT table1.place, table2.person FROM table1, table2
```

If "place" or "person" is empty in the database (NULL or if it was mistakenly entered as an empty string of length zero), I want it to insert `null` in that variable once I get it into a PHP array...  instead, it is showing up as `string of length zero`.

The first question is, why would this be happening?

The second question is, as a fix, I was thinking to assign it a string if the DB field is a string of length zero or null - this way we are taking ownership of the issue...

What's the best fix here?

**update**

Just to add, the point here is to get this for use in Smarty.  With Smarty, isset() evaluates "true" on a string of zero length, AND it seems to evaluate true even for a NULL inside those variables, so maybe this is more of a smarty issue??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`NULLIF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif):

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(table1.place, '') AS place,
    NULLIF(table2.person, '') AS person
FROM table1, table2
```